# Use Angular 2 with Electron (Angular CLI)

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I generated a new Angular 2 project using the new [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/).
Now I don't want to use Angular in browser but in an electron app.
Therefore I created a file for the main process of electron and after building my Angular app with `ng build` in terminal, the app was not working as expected.

File for Main Process of Electron:

```
var electron = require("electron");
var {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

app.on('ready', () => {
    var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
});
```

Error in DevTools:

```
file:///vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

I also know that you essentially need a web server to run Angular 2 Applications and I think my app does not work because Electron loads the App via the `file://` protocol.

But I really want to use Electron in conjunction with Angular 2; so my question is if this is possible and if so how I need to modify the generated Angular Template from the cli utility.

Comment: First search result https://auth0.com/blog/2015/12/15/create-a-desktop-app-with-angular-2-and-electron/

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know how to modify the template generated by the Angular CLI.

Comment: Just change the base href from href="/" to href="./" which will allow the app to run

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also change

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="./">
```

Answer (score 6):

After reading something about the Angular 2 Router yesterday, I figured out that the problem is caused by this line in the `index.html`

```
<base href="/">
```

By replacing it with a dynamically set base everything works as expected.

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This Github project by 'maximegris' sets up the environment for working with Angular 5 and Electron.

https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron

It proved to be a life saver for me. Hope you find this helpful too.

Answer (score -2):

download angular.js from the CDN and put it in your app folder. Then in your html file use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
```

Unlike a browser electron will not have a problem picking up angular.js from your file system.